# ebay api entries per page

Tags: c#, vb.net, ebay-api

Using the code bellow I get the amount of my sellers list MAX 200 per page.

I read [Ebay API Reference](https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/GetSellerList.html) that it is possible to have up to 5000 records returned. The only it says I need to do is to set the `DetailLevelCodeType` to return me only data I need. In my specific case to specify I only need to return `item.Title` and `Item.Quantity`, `Item.SellingStatus.CurrentPrice.Value`

What should I change the retrieve up to 5000 records?

```
Try
            Dim ApicallItem As GetItemCall = New GetItemCall(Context)

            Dim apicall As GetSellerListCall = New GetSellerListCall(Context)

            apicall.DetailLevelList.Add(DetailLevelCodeType.ReturnAll)

            apicall.Pagination = New PaginationType()

            apicall.Pagination.PageNumber = 1

            'apicall.Pagination.EntriesPerPage = 200

            apicall.UserID = myCfg.EbayUserId

            Dim dateValue As DateTime = DateTime.Now
            Dim d As DateTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-90)

            apicall.StartTimeFilter = New TimeFilter(d.Date + New TimeSpan(0, 0, 0), dateValue.Date + New TimeSpan(23, 59, 59))

            Dim sellerlist As ItemTypeCollection = apicall.GetSellerList()
            Dim item As ItemType

            For Each item In sellerlist
                If item.Quantity <> 0 Then
                    ' DO MY CODE
                End If
            Next item

        Catch ex As Exception
            WriteLog("Error while getting sellers list: " & ex.Message)
        End Try
```

Comment: Whoever upvoted this should post an explanation since they apparently think it's "useful and clear:.

Comment: I need to return up to those 5000 records from ebay. The columns i need are listed above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the solutions is to first time read all items without details. And the for each of those item run again api call to check info of it.

```
  For Each Items In sellerlist
                Dim ApiOneItem As GetItemCall = New GetItemCall(Context)
                ApiOneItem.DetailLevelList.Add(DetailLevelCodeType.ReturnAll)

                Item = ApicallItem.GetItem(Items.ItemID)
                If Item.Quantity <> 0 Then
                End if
  Next
```